# Determining whether a set of vectors is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have a set of vectors

$U = \{(r, 3s, r-2)\ |$ $r$ and $s$ in $R$}

If I let $r = 1$, and $s = 1$, I get a vector (1, 3, -1).

If I multiply that by 2, I get the vector (2, 6, -2).

Since the new vector is not obtainable by substitution, this set of vectors is not in $R^3$.

At first instead of multiplying the vector by 2, I was using a constant $c$. However, I ended up with $(cr, 3cs, c(r-2))$. Since $r$ and $s$ are real numbers, they are still real numbers when multiplied by $c$. So I first thought it was closed under multiplication, but I'm obviously wrong.

Can someone explain to me how to properly support my answer using constants?

Comment: Using $c$ was fine...the point isn't that the three coordinates are real, it's that they don't have the desired form ($c(r-2)≠cr-2$).

Comment: You could use the fact that $0$ must be in the subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should take Harto's suggestion to merely check whether $0$ is in the set, but you can use your calculation.

Namely, to check whether the scalar multiple $\big(cr, 3cs, c(r - 2)\big)$ of a generic vector $(r, 3s, r - 2)$ is in the set $U = \{(r, 3s, r - 2) : r, s \in \Bbb R\}$, we certainly need the first coordinate to be two more than the last coordinate. So, we check: if we subtract $2$ from the first coordinate, do we get the last coordinate?

$$cr - 2 \overset{?}= c(r - 2) = cr - 2c, $$

which is certainly not true whenever $c \neq 1$. Thus, only the trivial scalar multiple (scaling by $c = 1$) of any vector in $U$ is also in $U$, and it must not be a subspace.